# Spring jms 4.3.8 vs 4.0.2 with activemq 5.13.0 issue

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

We're facing a strange issue after we attempted upgrade of spring-jms-4.0.2 to 4.3.8 and activemq stayed at 5.13.0.

what we're witnessing is a continuous loop at either spring-jms or activemq side and CPU consistently pegged at around 20-40 range after we starts the app in Tomcat.

IF WE GO back and just replace spring-jms 4.3.8 in lib with 4.0.2 version everything behaves normally after the start.

the concurrent consumers are 2 with cache level set to 3 for "DefaultMessageListenerContainer" in spring.

Here are few indicators:

We enabled the debug logging for both springframework and activemq and what we see in spring log are 3 lines only irrespective of spring jms jar version.

```
2017-06-22T12:09:02,928 DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Established shared JMS Connection
2017-06-22T12:09:02,930 DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Resumed paused task: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker@bd71008
2017-06-22T12:09:02,930 DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Resumed paused task: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker@7814de81
```

But here is the difference between activemq logs

when we used spring-jms-4.0.2

```
2017-06-22 12:00:46,921 | DEBUG | Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=11, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, StackTraceEnabled=true, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,922 | DEBUG | tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=11, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,922 | DEBUG | tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=11, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,927 | DEBUG | Setting up new connection id: ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1, address: tcp://127.0.0.1:49504, info: ConnectionInfo {commandId = 1, responseRequired = true, connectionId = ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1, clientId = ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-0:1, clientIp = null, userName = null, password = *****, brokerPath = null, brokerMasterConnector = false, manageable = true, clientMaster = true, faultTolerant = true, failoverReconnect = false} | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,935 | DEBUG | Tomcat01.CE01 adding consumer: ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1:-1:1 for destination: ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue,ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,973 | DEBUG | Tomcat01.CE01 adding consumer: ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1:2:1 for destination: queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,976 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1:2:1, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,976 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=1, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request
2017-06-22 12:00:46,976 | DEBUG | Tomcat01.CE01 adding consumer: ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1:1:1 for destination: queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,977 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:39235aa-49503-1498147246722-1:1:1:1, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,977 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request
2017-06-22 12:00:46,978 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:00:46,978 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49504@61616
2017-06-22 12:01:04,340 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request expiring messages .. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[Tomcat01.CE01] Scheduler
2017-06-22 12:01:04,342 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request expiring messages done. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[Tomcat01.CE01] Scheduler
2017-06-22 12:01:04,342 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request
```

And, when we used upgraded spring-jms-4.3.8 or .9

```
2017-06-22 12:09:03,037 | DEBUG | Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=11, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, StackTraceEnabled=true, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,037 | DEBUG | tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=11, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,038 | DEBUG | tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=11, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,043 | DEBUG | Setting up new connection id: ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1, address: tcp://127.0.0.1:49636, info: ConnectionInfo {commandId = 1, responseRequired = true, connectionId = ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1, clientId = ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-0:1, clientIp = null, userName = null, password = *****, brokerPath = null, brokerMasterConnector = false, manageable = true, clientMaster = true, faultTolerant = true, failoverReconnect = false} | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,051 | DEBUG | Tomcat01.CE01 adding consumer: ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1:-1:1 for destination: ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue,ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,092 | DEBUG | Tomcat01.CE01 adding consumer: ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1:2:1 for destination: queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,095 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1:2:1, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,095 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=1, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request
2017-06-22 12:09:03,096 | DEBUG | Tomcat01.CE01 adding consumer: ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1:1:1 for destination: queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,096 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:39235aa-49635-1498147742821-1:1:1:1, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,097 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request
2017-06-22 12:09:03,097 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,105 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,114 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,114 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,114 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,114 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,115 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
2017-06-22 12:09:03,115 | DEBUG | queue://company.CD.Tomcat01.Repo.Request, subscriptions=2, memory=0%, size=0, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:49636@61616
```

If we look at the difference between two activemq logs,

it shows that the queue subscriptions line is being printed just once or twice and then after a gap of 30 seconds the expiry time kicks in and circle continues

But in 2nd log the expiry never kicks in and that queue subscription line is printed every ms and logs goes into GB in few minutes so some kind of loop.

We're trying to debug this but if someone has any idea or suggestion please pass it through.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, the upgraded 4.3.8 version now has 0 for receivetimeout instead of earlier -1 for waiting until it gets a new message which we had used and that why it was trying to get the message from the broker (activemq) in a loop and and bombarded it with those calls which caused the continues CPU usage.

Code snippet from JmsDestinationAccessor class.

```
protected Message receiveFromConsumer(MessageConsumer consumer, long timeout) throws JMSException {
    if (timeout > 0) {
        return consumer.receive(timeout);
    }
    else if (timeout < 0) {
        return consumer.receiveNoWait();
    }
    else {
        return consumer.receive();
    }
}
```